# Access Database not updating with OleDb

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-update, oledb

Here's my update method

```
public void Update(string query, List<OleDbParameter> parameters)
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbTransaction transaction = null;
            query = "UPDATE " + query;


            foreach (OleDbParameter parameter in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }

            this._Connect();

            transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Connection = _connection;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
            cmd.Prepare();
            int linesUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();

            this._Disconnect();

        }
```

Full class

```
 public class DBAdapter
    {
        private OleDbConnection _connection;

        private void _Connect()
        {
            this._connection = new OleDbConnection();
            _connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString;
            _connection.Open();
        }

        private void _Disconnect()
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }


        public void Update(string query, List<OleDbParameter> parameters)
        {
            ...
        }

    }
```

When I launch my application, this works well :

1. I select user by id
2. I store data in an object, I display the user's name. Then I modify user's name property.
3. I save it to database
4. I select again the same user
5. I display again the user's name : value displayed was changed, so the update method works.

But when I close my app and launch it again, It displays me the old value, then the new value, like I didn't make any changes. What's wrong with my code ?

**EDIT :** I found the problem. My .mdb file is located in //Assets/Database/, when I run my app, the file is copied in bin/Debug/assets/Databases/. 
How should I update the original file ?

**EDIT (2) :** Solved! [Can I commit changes to actual database while debugging C# in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677861/can-i-commit-changes-to-actual-database-while-debugging-c-sharp-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

just you can change path of connection string to update you'r original file but i dont recommend you i recommend you to right click on original file in solution explorer and select properties and set "Copy to out put directory" to "Copy if newer"

Comment: That's exactly what I did! (: