# Delete & Insert Problems to Access DB with Adapters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am at the point of giving up...  I am using DataAdapters with a connected Access database, (tested OK), the dataset gets updated fine but the database, which is located in my project root folder never gets updated when I try to Insert or Delete.  Here is what I am working with for a Delete;

```
Private Sub btnDeleteJob_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteJob.Click
    Dim delJobID = ComboBox2.SelectedValue
    Dim delJobRowAdpt As New DCGDataSetTableAdapters.MainTableAdapter
    Dim delJobRow As DCGDataSet.MainRow
    Dim intDelete As Integer
    delJobRow = DCGDataSet.Main.FindByID(delJobID)
    delJobRow.Delete()
    intDelete = delJobRowAdpt.Update(DCGDataSet.Main)
    If intDelete = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Job Deleted")
        'comboClear()
        clearTabOne()
        'ComboBox2.SelectedValue = -1
        Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet.Main)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Job Failed to Delete")
    End If
    ComboBox2.SelectedValue = -1
End Sub
```

And my Insert code;

```
Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click
    ' Add new Job to the database
    Dim newJobRow As New DCGDataSetTableAdapters.MainTableAdapter
    Dim intInsert As Integer
    Dim jobText = txtBoxAddNewJob.Text
    intInsert = newJobRow.InsertJob(jobText) 'InsertJob Adapter = INSERT INTO `Main` (`tbl_Job_Name`) VALUES (?)
    If intInsert = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("New Job Added")
        ' Update the comboBox values
        newJobRow.Fill(DCGDataSet.Main)
        'Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DCGDataSet.Main)
        'newJobRow.Insert(jobText)
        newJobRow.Update(DCGDataSet.Main)
        'DCGDataSet.AcceptChanges()
        txtBoxAddNewJob.Text = ""
        clearTabOne() ' Label5.Visible = False     ComboBox3.Visible = False
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Job Not Added")
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is my dataSet
[image]

If I close my app and open the database file in my Bin/Debug folder, the changes are there, but only until I run the app again.  I know I'm close, but I'm stuck, I need another pair of eyes...

Comment: _the database, which is located in my project root folder, never gets updated_ Something here is confusing.

Comment: The datasource .accdb file itself is in the project folder, C:\Users\mgfranz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DCG.

What is odd, (or is it normal), to have another copy of the db in C:\Users\mgfranz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DCG\DCG, and still another one in C:\Users\mgfranz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DCG\DCG\bin\Debug.

Comment: The last one is the effect of having the property Copy To Output Directory set to something different to Copy Never. In this case your db is copied to the output directory if the condition in Copy to Output Directory is met. The output directory is defined in your project properties and could be changed at your will. So perhaps something has been changed there. Remember that your program (WinForms) is executed from the output directory unless you change it in the properties of your project so your relative paths should be resilient to this situation

Comment: I understand that, and it makes sense, my property is set to Copy if Newer.  But is it possible to have changes done and saved to the actual database in Project root?  Right now I have to copy the .accdb from Bin to Project\DCG\DCG every time I make changes to the db.

Comment: Yes, set the proper path in your app.config ConnectionString section. (As a side note, Access changes the timestamp of your accdb file just opening it. It is not necessary to make actual changes to your data or schema)

Comment: Where do I do that?  Project > Properties?

Comment: In your Project->Properties->Settings. You should have a ConnectionString line with the informations used by your TableAdapters to connect to your Access database. You could work from here

Comment: It's set to C:\Users\mgfranz\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DCG\DCG\DCG.accdb which is the proper path for the connection string to the actual db.

Answer (score 1):

I guess when you add your database to project, you have allowed to visual studio that create a copy of  your database.

test this solution please: remove your database from your project and add it again. This Time , in last step of adding, when visual studio ask you about create a copy of database in your solution directory, choose **NO**.

if you choose YES, each time you run your program, a new copy of your database will create in Bin/Debug folder and your changes affect this copy and when you stop execution , this copy will be removed.

notice:don't forget that correct your connection string if you have it

I hope that help you this answer.
excuse me if my writing is not correct. I'm beginner in English language but I  will learn it soon...

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to change the **Copy to Output Directory property on the database file** in your project's root. The default setting for the property is "Copy Always." The setting you probably want is **"Copy If Newer"**. This will copy the database from the project root only if you make some change to the database and build your project. Now, if you make some changes in a test run, those changes will still be there in your next test run.

This guy had the same problem: [Can I commit changes to actual database while debugging C# in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677861/can-i-commit-changes-to-actual-database-while-debugging-c-sharp-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I had already thought of that.  The Property for the .accdb is set for Copy If Newer.  My debug constantly reverts to the DataSource DB which never sees changes made to the dataset updates.