# stop database from copying?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

So I have a database that is connected to my c# application. When I save data to the database it is there until I close the application. Once I restart the application and check the database...all the data I previously entered is gone.

I am using a local database...its a .mdf file. I know I could use SQL server management studio and use sqlexpress but I don't understand how to do it...i have tried and just had lots of problems. The database is set to copy in the visual studio settings...i was wondering if I have to change this setting for it to save the data for good. I am also running the application in debug mode and I have ran it without the debugger and the same thing happens.

Anyone had the same problem?

```
      using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
      using (SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
      {
           myCmd.Parameters.Add("@nickname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtNickname.Text.Trim();
           myCmd.Parameters.Add("@websiteUsername", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
           myCmd.Parameters.Add("@websiteURL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtURL.Text.Trim();
           myCmd.Parameters.Add("@websitePassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
           myCmd.Parameters.Add("@websiteEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
           myCmd.Parameters.Add("@websiteEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtAbout.Text.Trim();

           try
           {
                conn.Open()

                int iAffectedRows = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (iAffectedRows > 0)
                {
                     MessageBox.Show("Successful");
                }
                else
                {
                     MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful");
                }
                conn.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
           }
       }
  }
```

}

There is not any coding errors given by

Comment: sounds like you need to add an explicit call to `Commit` can you show your query .. also show the code as to how you are updating and or adding / inserting values into your current database also `I could use SQL server management studio and use sqlexpress but I don't understand how to do it.` there are plenty of tutorials and existing working examples on the net if you are not sure how to do this with `Sql Server or Sql Server Express` then do a simple google search

Comment: Are you using entity framework? Is it possible you have the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` database initializer set? It drops the database and recreates it the first time you use the database context.

Comment: I think this question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677861/can-i-commit-changes-to-actual-database-while-debugging-c-sharp-in-visual-studio

Comment: I have tried to look it up and I get errors everytime when I try to use the database in vs. That's why I can't use management studio. Also I am not using entity. And @referscus I think that might be what I am looking for. Sorry about the code I can only do so much on my phone

Comment: You failed to include your INSERT or UPDATE statement (the one you are passing to `new SQLCommand()`). Without it, it's pretty difficult to see what might be wrong with your code.

Comment: It sounds like your data file is being overwritten at compile time. What happens if you just run the program directly from the compile output? Go to bin\debug and run the exe, do some database work, close it, run it again.