# Why the row is not being inserted into the DB? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

### Last update

I think I found why this is happening. Everytime I try to debug my application, a new Database file is created by Visual Studio on the debug folder. This file is deleted when my app closes, so every change I make during runtime is deleted. I don't know how to change this, but I will post it when I figure it out.

**

### Edited to add more info

**

I created a class in C# to handle the Database operations. I have a method to read from the DB that works just fine. But when I try to insert rows, nothing happens. There's no error or exception, the code runs just as it's supposed to, reaches the "return true" statement, but when I check the DB after, I haven't got any new data. The DB is empty by now, so it doesn't have any conflicts with any unique fields. The id field is not auto-generated, so that's not the problem either.

Here's the code:

```
public bool saveCity(City c)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[cities] ([Id], [Name], [Latitude], [Longitude], [Radius], [LastUpdate])" +
            " VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Latitude, @Longitude, @Radius, @LastUpdate);";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", c.Id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", c.Name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude", c.Latitude);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitude", c.Longitude);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Radius", c.Radius);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdate", c.Update);
                    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The connString is defined as a class field:

```
connString = Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString;
```

I don't have any triggers in my DB, or nothing that could delete my rows after inserted. At the moment, it has only one table, cities, which looks like this:

[image: DB screen capture]

The code of the City class:

```
class City
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
        public int Radius;
        public double Latitude;
        public double Longitude;
        public DateTime Update;

        public City()
        {
            Id = -1;
            Name = "";
            Radius = 0;
            Latitude = 0;
            Longitude = 0;
            Update = DateTime.Now;
        }


}
```

It's my first time working with C# DB connections, so probably there's something really obvious and stupid I'm missing, but it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Instead of hiding any errors, either log the exceptions that occur or remove the `catch` statement completely. Hiding faults behind status codes isn't a safe practice. In any case, you have to post any errors that occur *in the question itself*, otherwise people won't be able to help

Comment: BTW, it's also a bad idea to use globals or even fields for connections. They should be opened right before they are used and placed in a `using` statement. As it is, your code leaks connections when exceptions occur. `using` ensures the connection is always closed and disposed.

Comment: But there are no errors, that's the thing. The code runs just fine, but when it ends, there are not new rows on the DB,

Comment: Also, don't make `connection` static. Always create, open, use and close it where you use the connection, best by using the `using`-statement.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Your code hides exceptions, how do you know that there are no errors?

Comment: How do know you have a connection open

Comment: Even without errors, global/static connections means that you don't know if there is an uncommited transaction open that prevents the changes from appearing, or rolls them back when the application terminates. Do you use transactions?

Comment: Maybe your inserted row have conflict in Primary or Unique columns with existing row ?

Comment: You are also inserting the ID. Is this field perhaps an auto-generated field?

Comment: Because I debugged it, and it reached the "return true" statement.

Comment: The database is empty, there are not possible conficts. I'm inserting the ID on purpose, because it's supposed to be the same Id as in other DB, so it's not auto-generated. I will try creating the connection inside the method.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time someone is inserting into one database and looking at another

Comment: I tried moving the connection from the class fields to inside the method. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Trigger deleting the new record perhaps?

Comment: I don't have any triggers on the DB. I don't understand, this issue is driving me crazy.

Comment: Please post your `City` model

Comment: Quote: *"But there are no errors, that's the thing."* Sir, you are catching all errors and just bailing out of the function. Are you sure you have no error ?

Comment: Not directly related to your question: do you care about **transactions**? You really should. It is a very bad idea to open transaction (no matter if explicit or implicit) in the data access layer to perform a single action. Transactions should span the whole business operation. Otherwise, you'll run into big problems as soon as you have more than one operation at once. Read about ACID. It's crucial.

Comment: Try using SQL profiler - did the SQL statement actually execute? What if you try to execute it using Management Studio?

Comment: @SQLPolice plenty of NOT INs encountered since our last encounter

Comment: @DrewPierce You are quite bravehearted, I must say.  `NOT IN`s look so tame and harmless, but when you don't pay attention, they come with a `NULL` and tear down your application. BTW, you were really right with your assumption here, have you read the answer ?

Comment: @DrewPierce The DB was re-created everytime during startup ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Visual Studio creates a new instance of the DB everytime you try to debug. Someone posted a workaround for this issue, so here's the link:

[Can I commit changes to actual database while debugging C# in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677861/can-i-commit-changes-to-actual-database-while-debugging-c-sharp-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Include the data type and a question mark instead of @ in front of the parameter names as well. eg:

`string query = @"INSERT INTO cities (Id, name, coord_x, coord_y, radius, updated_at)" 
        + " VALUES (?id, ?name, ?lat, ?lng, ?rad, ?update)";`

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("?id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = c.Id
```

etc..

Hope this helps

Comment: It's the same. The code runs great, everything looks like it went fine, but no changes on the DB.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is a `Mysql` DB you are using right?

Comment: I'm working with the Service Based DB included in Visual Studio 2013 when yout generate a database-driven application project

Comment: Now that doesn't sound exactly like mySQL does it? Try the following: wrap your Command in a `Transaction` using block, then first execute a command `SET IDENTITY_INSERT cities ON`, then execute your `INSERT` command, then execute `SET IDENTITY_INSERT cities OFF` then `COMMIT` your transaction. See if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: The response is 'Table 'cities' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.'. I don't have the identity property because I don't want my IDs to be auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

Change `double` to `decimal`, specify DB type in `Parameters.Add` and change `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (@id,...)` syntax to `INSERT INTO ... SELECT @id,...`. Maybe one of them is the problem but it is better to change all.