# Database Saves and Shows In Access While Program Still Running , But When I Close And Run Again , I Will Have To Sign Up Again Then Login

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

Good day to everyone,
I'm working on my final project, and i've created a signin and signup form, where the user will have to singup the first time he or she tries to login, But here is the case when i signup, the account will be created and i'll be able to login with the details used in creating the account, but immediately i close the program as i am still working on the project, then i try to run again, i'll have to signup again in other to move on to the next step.

My question here is that, is it because i'm still working on the program that is why the data isn't saving, so when i'm done then i build the project, i wont face that issue, or i'm missing something.

i want the data used in creating the account be saved in the database, so that the user wont have to be signing up everytime the program is runned.

Please any help, project needs to submitted within this week...

The codes are below:

```
 Private Sub loginsignin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loginsignin.Click
        If txtloginusername.Text = Nothing Or txtloginpass.Text = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter credentials", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        Using Command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbllogin WHERE uname = @loginusername AND pass = @loginpass", con)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtloginusername.Text.Trim
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtloginpass.Text.Trim

            Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar())

            If count > 0 Then
                Me.Hide()
                Dashboard.Show()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Oops!, Invalid Credentials", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnsignup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsignup.Click
        If txtfname.Text = Nothing Or txtlname.Text = Nothing Or txtuname.Text = Nothing Or txtmobile.Text = Nothing Or txtpass.Text = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter credentials", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If txtmobile.Text.Length < 10 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Telephone Number!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        Using command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbllogin WHERE mobile = @mobile", con)
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@mobile", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtmobile.Text

            Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar())

            If count > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Oops!, Preregistered Telephone Number.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End Using

        Using create As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tbllogin ([uname], [pass], [mobile], [fname], [lname]) VALUES (@uname,
        @pass, @mobile, @fname, @lname)", con)
            create.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter(“@uname”, OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtuname.Text
            create.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtpass.Text
            create.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@mobile", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtmobile.Text
            create.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@fname", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtfname.Text
            create.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@lname", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtlname.Text

            If create.ExecuteNonQuery Then
                MessageBox.Show("Account created", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Else
                MsgBox("Registration Failed.")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtfname.Text = ""
    End Sub
```

Comment: Access isn't MySQL, which database you use? If it's Access, then this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677861/can-i-commit-changes-to-actual-database-while-debugging-c-sharp-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Don't place your database in your project's bin folder.

Comment: Well I suspect user9938 might be on the right track, you’ve got a few other issues in there.  Global connections are very problematic.  Connections are disposable so should be wrapped in a using command as per the commands.  And you’re mixing parameters.add() and parameters.addwithvalue() syntax

Comment: @user9938, Please I wasn't the one who added the database to bin, I think It was automatically sent there, because the original location still has a copy of the database there, and a copy is also at the main project location where the bin folder is...

Comment: So please how do I go about it...

Comment: Who created the database? Are you working with a team of developers? It's not clear how the database was created. One way to resolve it is to create an installer and run the installed version. Another option, while in development, is to place your database in a folder in `%ProgramData%`, `%AppData%,`, `%UserProfile%\Documents`, etc.... Update your connection string accordingly. Deployment is part of the development process.