# I can't insert data when closing application

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there anything wrong here? I've tried putting `Application.Exit()` and `this.Close()` and it's working but it's not inserting any data from my MS Access. Im getting the info from form1 login textboxes to detect the user ID and and user Type and insert the Log for TIME OUT, STATUS, USER ID and USER TYPE.

What im expecting here is when closing one form, the application will close and insert Logs in MS Acces.

```
        private void btnCloseLight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            { 
                //For Getting data from Login Form
                LoginForm form1instance = new LoginForm();
                string userId = form1instance.Form1userLoginTextBox;
                string password = form1instance.Form1passLoginTextBox;

                connection.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [UserID], [UserType] FROM tblUser WHERE UserID = @UserID AND Password = @Password", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);

                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    string userID = reader["UserID"].ToString();
                    int userType = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserType"]);

                    //Inserting Time OUT to tblLogs
                    RecordTimeOut(userID, userType);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Close();
                
            }
        }

        public void RecordTimeOut(string userId, int userType)
        {
            try
            {
                using (OleDbConnection insertConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string status = "TIME OUT";

                    insertConnection.Open();
                    cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblLogs ([Log Time], [STATUS], [UserID], [UserType]) VALUES ([@Log Time], [@STATUS], [@UserID], [@UserType])", connection);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Log Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", status);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userId);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserType", OleDbType.Integer).Value = userType;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Inserting Log: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

My Login:

```
#region LogIn
 public void OpenStudentForm()
 {
     //Close Login form
     this.Hide();

     //Shows the New Forms
     StudentForm stuForm = new StudentForm();
     stuForm.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close(); // Close the App is when this Form is Closed
     stuForm.Show();
 }

 public void OpenInstructorForm()
 {
     //Close Login form
     this.Hide();

     InstructorForm insForm = new InstructorForm();
     insForm.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close(); // Close the App is when this Form is Closed
     insForm.Show();
 }

 public void OpenSystemAdminForm()
 {
     //Close Login form
     this.Hide();

     SystemAdminForm sysAdminForm = new SystemAdminForm();
     sysAdminForm.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Close(); // Close the App is when this Form is Closed
     sysAdminForm.Show();
 }

 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string userIDLogin = userIdLoginTextBox.Texts;
     string passwordLogin = passwordLoginTextBox.Texts;

     try
     {
         connection.Open();
         cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [UserID], [UserType] FROM tblUser WHERE UserID = @UserID AND Password = @Password", connection);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userIDLogin);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passwordLogin);

         OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

         if (reader.Read())
         {
             string userID = reader["UserID"].ToString();
             int userType= Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserType"]);

             //Inserting Login Info to tblLogs
             InsertLoginLog(userID, userType);

             switch (userType)
             {
                 case 0: //Student
                     OpenStudentForm();
                     break;
                 case 1: //Instructor
                     MessageBox.Show("Instructor");
                     OpenInstructorForm();
                     break;
                 case 2: //System Admin
                     MessageBox.Show("System Admin");
                     OpenSystemAdminForm();
                     break;
                 default:
                     MessageBox.Show("Unknown User Type");
                     break;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Invalid User ID or Password");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
         if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
             connection.Close();
     }
 }

 public void InsertLoginLog(string userID, int userType)
 {

     try
     {
         using (OleDbConnection insertConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
         {
             string status = "TIME IN";

             insertConnection.Open();
             cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblLogs ([Log Time], [STATUS], [UserID], [UserType]) VALUES ([@Log Time], [@STATUS], [@UserID], [@UserType])", connection);

             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Log Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", status);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userID);
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserType", OleDbType.Integer).Value = userType;

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error inserting Log: " + ex.Message);
     }
 }
 #endregion
```

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint to make sure it's actually executing the lines. If you're debugging and the Access database is in the debug folder, by default it's always wiped out on each session.

Comment: @Martheen can you show it to me? Im sorry im not good with explaining only words

Comment: Since you just created a new `LoginForm` here: `LoginForm form1instance = new LoginForm();` (which you never show), how can it contain information about passwords or other stuff?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677861/can-i-commit-changes-to-actual-database-while-debugging-c-sharp-in-visual-studio

Comment: @Jimi oh sorry, i've added my login codes

Comment: Nope. I mean, in `btnCloseLight_Click` you have created a new instance of `LoginForm`. You never call its `Show()` / `ShowDialog()` method. So it doesn't contain any password or other User input. You probably want the instance of this Form that was used to add that information, right? Well, it's not this new instance. Set a breakpoint (F9, usually) in the `btnCloseLight_Click` event handler and check what `string userId`  & Co. contain

Comment: @Jimi yes i want to get the info from login textboxes from Login form to detect the current user logged in on the new form. What should i do to collect the info from there?

Comment: You need the instance of the `LoginForm` Form that was used to collect this information. Or, better, store the required information in, e.g., the Project's Settings after the *login procedure* has completed successfully (so you can fetch the data from there and you don't need `LoginForm` anymore) -- BTW, you should never store a Connection object (or the OleDbCommand, etc.). It should be declared in-place with an `using` statement, so it's disposed right after use

Comment: Note that I'm not suggesting to store a password anywhere. You just need an User ID to identify the current User, not the password

Comment: @Jimi can you show me how to  do it?